# Событие по клику (тапу) в A-Frame с использованием AR.js

Tags: javascript

Ребята кто знает, пожалуйста, выручите! Сломал голову.
Пытаюсь разработать веб-приложение с доп.реальностью на основе a-frame и ar.js.
Как можно повесить событие (например переход на сайт) на сущность (например a-image)? Луч курсора всегда расположен по центру, и событие срабатывает только когда он сталкивается с сущностью. Мне же нужно чтобы я мог нажать(тапнуть на смартфоне) в любом месте на нужную сущность и событие повешенное на энного срабатывало. Возможно ли например вычислять координаты клика и подставлять их в компонент позиции курсора? Рад услышать какие угодно идеи реализации, буду бесконечно благодарен!